# Spacing elements in HTML

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to create spaces between elements without using margin and actual spaces?

Markup:

```
<div><span>A</span><span>B<span><span>C<span></div>
```

Result:

```
ABC
```

The reason, I need to catch click event of the `div` when the user clicks between the `span` elements.

I tried using the `word-spacing` but obviously it wasn't created for that so it won't work.

Comment: You can use `span{  letter-spacing: 10px }`.

Comment: `A&nbsp;B&nbsp;C = A B C`

Comment: @ketan good point - that does technically answer the question, but it doesn't seem to solve his problem. I took my best guess in my answer that he does actually want margins so that the parent div can be clicked. That just leaves me with the question of why he wanted to avoid margins to begin with...

Comment: @m59 I think his comment answers the question. The margin of `span`, if I add it, blocks the parent `div`.

Comment: @dpp Margins don't block the parent. Padding would block the parent, but margins don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it fits your need. The letters are spaced as though there is a character between them, and you can run code only when that space in between is clicked. Perhaps you really do want to avoid margins, but it's hard to say without knowing your reasoning there.

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target === this) {
    console.log('div clicked');
  }
});
```

```css
span {
  margin: .5em;
}

span:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

span:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>C</span>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, my bad. I also have event handler for span and I added `stopPropagation`. I'll try if I can remove it.

Comment: so `if (e.target === this)` did the trick... I never thought of doing that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
     span
     { 
       letter-spacing: 10px; 
     }
```

Instead of `word-spacing` It will create spaces between elements. 
like: A  B  C.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use padding.

```
span {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it the other way around?

**HTML:**

```
<div>A<span class="spc"></span>B<span class="spc"></span>C<span class="spc"></span>D</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.spc{padding-left:10px;}
```

**js/jQuery:**

```
$('.spc').click(function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6pwv8fjq/)

Comment: it doesn't use space and margin but it does add new elements between them. Sorry, but I want nothing between `span`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z6ff6wnc/3/)**

**CSS:**

```
div > span {
    width: 30% !important;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div><span>A</span><span>B</span><span>C</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create spaces between two letter without margin then you can put

```
padding-right
```

or

```
padding-left
```

I hope it will wok for you

Answer (score 0):

If only the space between the spans is to be clickable, apply the click function to the div, add spaces with `&nbsp;`, and then prevent propagation on the child spans.

```js
$('#container').click(function() {
  alert('click');
})

$('#container span').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid #888888;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>A</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>B</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>C</span>&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways spacing can be added to HTML by using `<br></br>` or tab which syntax look `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` A paragraph syntax can also be useful `<p></p>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="span-btn-group">
<span>A</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>C</span>
</div>

.span-btn-group span
{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 6px 10px;
 background: green;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
```